# Relationship to nodes of different types in neomodel

Tags: django, neo4j, neomodel

Can I have a relationship to different kind of nodes?

I need something like

```
rel = RelationshipTo('NodeTypeOne|NodeTypeTwo', 'REL');
```

or

```
rel = RelationshipTo('StructuredNode', 'REL');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the relationship into two relationship declarations, within the class you defined:

```
rel1 = RelationshipTo('NodetypeOne', 'REL')
rel2 = RelationshipTo('NodetypeTwo', 'REL')
```

A quick example:

```
class NodeType1(StructuredNode):
    name = StringProperty()

class NodeType2(StructuredNode):
    name = StringProperty()

class NodeType3( StructuredNode ):
    name = StringProperty()

    rel1 = RelationshipTo( 'NodeType1', 'REL')
    rel2 = RelationshipTo( 'NodeType2', 'REL')

n1 = NodeType1(name='nodetype1').save()
n2 = NodeType2(name='nodetype2').save()
n3 = NodeType3(name='nodetype3').save()
n3.rel1.connect(n1)
n3.rel2.connect(n2)
```

We'll end up with `n3` having connections to `n1` and `n2` with the same relationship name `REL`. Here's the end result:

[image]